# Remove 'Sign Up' link section from facebook likebox social plugin

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

Remove the ‘Sign up’ link in like-box head from iframe in facebook social plugin and increase the width of iframe as width :100% (percentage) as it can now only increase by pixels.

Answer (score 0):

In general 100% width of iFrame width means it aquires the width of its container element. We cannot change contents inside iFrame. 
But, after you have got some user profiles to show. Make your own facebook likebox. That is completely hosted on your server. Normally facebook iFrame takes too much time to load.